# Get "Internal Server Error Undefined index: handle"

Tags: matrix, database, server

Hi I was trying to save the matrix field and got the error:
"Internal Server Error

Undefined index: handle"

I checked out all fields' handles and they are all in place.

Is there any reason causing the error?
[image]

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Can you find that error in your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` folder and post the full stack trace leading up to it? Alternatively, you can enable devMode (http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#devMode), reproduce the error and get the stack trace in your browser.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I uploaded the errors with devMode on. Hope it helps to explain the problems I've got. Thank you!

Comment: It's hard to tell which Matrix field it's complaining about from the stack trace, but can you try going through each of your Matrix field settings pages and re-saving their settings and see if the error goes away?

Comment: I went inside each matrix field settings and resaved them (no errors came up), but still got the same error when save the whole matrix.

Comment: I thought it could be the matrix fields maximum number reached, so I tried to delete one block type. And I received a "type" error on saving as newly attached in the post.

Comment: Yeah, something seems jacked up with your setup.  Can you submit a ticket from your dashboard's Get Help widget and let it send along a db backup along with log files?  Also, point us to an entry and Matrix field where we can try to reproduce what you're seeing.

Comment: I'm having the same issue when creating a field in a matrix. Was there any luck resolving this?

Comment: Just had the same issue adding a field to matrix block...

Answer (score 2):

This ended up being an environmental issue with semi-largish Matrix fields.

The three most common culprits are your php.ini file's [max_input_vars](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars), [max_input_nesting_level](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-nesting-level) and [post_max_size](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) would would need to be adjusted upwards, but other settings might come into play depending on your environment an Matrix configuration.

Also, if your server is running anything like [mod_security](https://www.modsecurity.org/) or [Suhosin](https://suhosin.org/stories/index.html), they have additional settings that might need to be adjusted higher that could affect this.